# Springboot with KeyCloack server, implement own /login endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I configured SpringBoot application with OAuth resource server (keycloack) and it works great, but I want to use my springboot application endpoint for example /login to authenticate and get JWT token from keycloack, how to do this? Can I configure it somehow using OAuth2 library? Or I should write proxy-like implementation and do the request from /login to /auth/realms/myapp/protocol/openid-connect/auth?
Is it a good aproach anyway?
Great if someone have any example how it may work. I also want to create /register endpoint in the same way.